# Insert Query Error (Invalid Character)

Tags: sql, oracle

This query

```
insert into table-name(CONTRACT_TYPE,CATEGORY) ( 
select 'GOLDCHOICE','C-CLASS' 
from tablename2 
where model_no = '1'and part_number not in (
  select part_number from tablename3 
  where contract_type ='GOLDCHOICE' 
  and category = 'C-CLASS' 
  and model_number = '1')
);
```

is running successfully in Oracle(TOAD).

However, when I run it from asp.net (connected to oracle), it is throwing

> ORA-00911: invalid character

But without `'semicolon(;)'` it's running fine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Which provider do you use?

Comment: I am not using any provider. I directly connect by server name  through VPN.

Comment: From asp - how are you call the db?

Comment: string oradb = "Data Source=" + OracleServerName + ";User Id=" + UserName + ";Password=" + Password + ";"; am passing them through textbox, which is entered by the user

Comment: Please, post part of your asp cpde that run the query

Comment: public OracleConnection GetOracleCon()
    {
        string OraServerName = ServerList.Text;
        string UserName = txtusername.Text;
        string Pswrd = txtpwd.Text;
        string oradb = "Data Source=" + OraServerName + ";User Id=" + UserName + ";Password=" + Pswrd + ";";
        OracleConnection oraconn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        return oraconn;
    }

Comment: I tried adding BEGIN (queries) END;
some error is coming

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `;` from the end of your query. Some providers - like `ODP` - don't like the `;` in the end of query.

Comment: I cant run the query with semicolon(;) then?
And then while running multiple insert queries without semicolon(;), it is throwing "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" I need to run multiple queries. What can be done? Please help

Comment: Not best option, but youcan do single inserts in the loop. You can also try store procedure + binding arrays.

Comment: Try foreach(string query insertList) {your code here for single select}